Откуда в git bash берется корневая директория линукс системы?
Вопрос просто из любопытства. git bash эмулирует настоящую bash, многие линукс команды работают тут. Например, какой-нибудь git diff @~ | grep + спокойно выполняет свою функцию. Зная это, я ковырялся в git bash'е и при переходе в корень линукс системы cd / мы реально переходим в корень линукс системы. Разве что /home нету  При этом в папках можно ковыряться, они не пустые и заполнены вполне реальными файлами. Вот, например, содержимое /dev/: Вопрос: как все это реализовано и где я нахожусь на самом деле, когда копаюсь в этом "линуксе"? pwd ведет себя так, будто я в линуксе. А при возвращении в пользователи cd перекидывает в файловую систему в виндоус в пользователи.

Первый скриншот подозрительно напоминает папку установки git (по умолчанию c:\Program Files\Git\)

Приводить картинки вместо текста - плохая затея. Чтобы узнать, где реально находитесь, выполните pwd -W

Видимо, откуда-то отсюда (но каким конкретно образом появляются файлы в /dev, я описания не нашёл)
